# jQuery selector: Double :not not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Having this html:

```
<div><h1>1</h1></div>
<div>2</div>
<div><h1>3</h1></div>
```

This is returning 0:

```
$("div").filter(":not(:not(:has(h1)))").length
```

I've made some [testing here](http://jsfiddle.net/paska/h5PAm/2/) and the first two selectors are ok (without any filtering, and then just with one not).

This is a simpler model than my code. I really can't avoid both not's because one is added by a plugin and the other is being received in its options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know why this is happening but it got fixed on version 1.8. [Here is the same code with jQuery 1.8 working](http://jsfiddle.net/paska/h5PAm/1/).

If you can't change your version for some reason one workaround is changing the `.filter` for `.not`. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/paska/h5PAm/3/) it is working.

Comment: Sizzle's implementation of filter selectors was extremely buggy. jQuery 1.8 includes an overhauled Sizzle that fixes a large number of issues. I guess this is one of those issues.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the double 'not's like this ?

```
alert($("div").length);
alert($("div").filter(":not(:has(h1))").length);
alert($("div").filter(":has(h1)").length);​
```

Comment: As my question says: my script is much complex than what I posted. When of the not's is reveived in a plugin threw its settings; the other is being added by the plugin itself.

Comment: maybe you can set a boolean when it is set by plugin and and check for that boolean when the other not is to be added ?

Comment: But I still need the second not, whetever the first is added or not. The plugin parameter is a selector that means something. In the plugin I need all the elements that doesn't acomplish that something. If the caller of the plugin has that something selected by not, it is valid.